# Problem with scope in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, dojo

Having this JS file:

```
define(["dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/dom-class",
    "dojo/dom-attr",
    "dojo/query",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/string",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/sniff",
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/Deferred",
    "dijit/registry",
    "caretalks/utils/form/addressForm",
    "caretalks/dialogManager",

    "caretalks/utils/placeholders",
    "caretalks/widget/Button",
    "caretalks/widget/MenuItem",
    "caretalks/widget/form/Select",
    "caretalks/validation/Validator"],

    function(lang, dom, domClass, attr, query, on, string, construct, sniff, ready, Deferred, registry, addressForm, dialogManager,
            placeholders, Button, MenuItem, Select, Validator) {
```

and this function:

```
handleSuccess : function(response) {

    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
    var node = dom.byId("phoneNumber.errors");   <<--- returns null! 

},
```

and the call for the function:

```
var node1 = dom.byId("phoneNumber.errors");   <<--- returns NOT null!

var _self = this;
this.showPropagateChangeDialog(args.propagateChangesDialog, document.forms[args.formName]).then(function(){
    console.info('Posting ' + args.formName + ' to URL: ' + args.url + ' with: ', bindings);
    caretalks.requestManager.ajaxPost(bindings).then(_self.handleSuccess,placeholders.enable);
});
```

I need to get a `div` by using `dom.byId()`, when i'm using it outside of my function it returns the actual value that I need, but when it's inside the function it returns null.

The dom is initialized and `byId()` can be found there, but the needed value is returns `undefined`.

How can I solve this issue? 
What do I missing here?

Comment: Did you check the div is existed in DOM using Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: yes it is, I did get it but from other scope.
Is this issue related to scope chain ?

Comment: Can you post a sample fiddle or code that includes the method handleSuccess?

Comment: it's exists in the original message

Comment: I don't think it was a scope chain problem. dom.byId() returns null or undefined only when the corresponding node does not exist in browser DOM tree. You can replace the dom.byId("phoneNumber.errors") with document.getElementById("phoneNumber.errors") inside the handleSucess function to identify this.

Comment: I tried to use `document.getElementById("phoneNumber.errors")` and it remains `null`. I must emphasize that the `DOM` element is exist, also for other `DOM` elements it returns `null`